# USB Midi Keyboard causes ALSA Port Unsubscribed

Tags: alsa, midi

Ubuntu 16.04 with Casio CDP-120

When tracking midi data using aseqdump the notes on/off signals are recognised then what appears to be random (although by playing several keys at once, increases the speed of failure) a Port Unsubscribed message is signalled and the keyboard no longer responds until I quit aseqdump (CTRL+C) and restart it - the Midi keyboard does not need to have power recycled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that due to some electrical error on the bus, the PC thinks that the keyboard has disconnected. This is probably caused by the keyboard using more power than the port (hub) can supply.

Comment: dodgy cable - causing this I think - thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

So, sometimes just asking the question gets you the answer!

I tested everything with my laptop and it worked great - thought I'd try another usb cable and voila - success on the original PC!